# When deploying a MVC application to Default Web Site\MySite, the view engine searches up one level

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-deployment

I've got a MVC project that works fine in IIS Express in development, and works fine when I publish from VS 2012 to a root level web site on a server (IIS 6.1), but when I try to deploy it in a directory below "Default Web Site", for example "Default Web Site\MySite", the views aren't found properly.  It appears that the views are being searched for at "Default Web Site\Views", a level above where they should be, at "Default Web Site\MySite\Views".

I've confirmed that this is what is happening my copying my Views directory up one level and then the application runs fine.

How do I fix this so the that application searches for Views in the proper directory?

[image: Publish Web Dialog]

Comment: @Péter: Yes, have control of server.  Server had another site at 'Default Web Site'.  Deployed as above and set the app pool that I wanted for the sub site.

Answer (score 0):

Do you deploy the mvc application to virtual directory or application onto iis?
EDIT:
Do you prepare the MyServer to receive the web app? Do you have access the server itself?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand the question.  I have a MVC application that I'm publishing to a server, setting the Site name in the connection tab of the publish dialog to 'Default Web Site\MySite', The server field is 'http://MyServer/MySite' Destination URL is 'http://MyServer/MySite'

Comment: See comments above.  Probably better to have discussion in Question's comments rather than in an answer. (you may even want to delete this answer).  Is there a way to take this conversation off line without posting an email address or other contact info in the clear on SO?